# Does the vowel combination /ou/ appear in any Spanish words?

Tags: fonología, diptongos

Spanish has many [diphthongs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology#Diphthongs_and_triphthongs), but I have never noticed 'ou' appearing in a word except for [*bou*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=603lUyF) (a Catalan loanword), the surname [*Bousoño*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Bouso%C3%B1o), and the Kantian term [*noúmeno*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QerPXfG).

The sound does occur across word boundaries - *"teng**o u**na casa"* etc - and in some compound words e.g. *estadounidenses, genitourinario, finoúgrio*.

**Are there any other Spanish words that contain the combination of vowels /ou/** (as a diphthong or in hiatus)**?**

---

<sup>**Note:** I'm not including un-assimilated French/English loanwords like *coulis, rouge, touche, roulotte, bourbon, house* etc as they tend to be pronounced similarly to the original voice i.e. /u/ or /au/ e.g. in *sioux* and its assimilated form [*siux*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y31M8wW), or in [*output*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RLWOVVw).</sup>

---

**Source:**

> <sup>Bowen and Stockwell do not list /ow/ (written /ou/ in this note) among their syllabic nuclei. It occurs in admittedly rare forms such as *bou* 'fishing with a net dragged by two boats' and the proper name *Bousoño*.</sup>
>
> <sup>• [*"A Note on Spanish Semivowels"*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/411006), Sol Saporta (1956)</sup>

Comment: Si hablamos de pronunciación, en el habla inculta de Chile sí existe la combinación cuando se vocaliza la b del grupo br, p. ej. _poureza_, _courador_ y _souras_ (pobreza, cobrador y sobras). No sé cómo se llama ese fenómeno.

Comment: @Rodrigo No tenía idea de que eso ocurría. En todo el romance es común que se pierda, se asimile o se vocalice una oclusiva en final de sílaba, pero esto es más raro. ¿La -r- intermedia es una *ere* normal o es más fuerte?

Comment: @Rodrigo parece que /ou/ aparece en más circunstancias en el habla chilena: `Chilean Spanish avoids spirant-liquid clusters by means of vocalization and coda parsing of the first member of the cluster, /logro/ [lo.ṷɾo] *[lo.ɣɾo]`  [*Spanish Phonology: A Syllabic Perspective*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=uMhdpZSnZ2cC&q="chilean+spanish+avoids") (p28)

Comment: @pablodf76 Es una r normal. También con otras vocales y, como muestra ukemi, con g. Per ejemplo negro/neuro, Gabriel/gauriel. _[¡Andate caurito!](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22andate+caurito%22)_ es una exclamación que viene de "cabro", que significa chiquillo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realizando una búsqueda para palabras que contienen "ou" en el DLE, se genera la siguiente lista:

> - bou, proustiano, soul<sup>1</sup>
> - estadounidense, estadounidismo, genitourinario
> - *art nouveau, boutade, boutique, coulis, gouache, gourmet, mousse, rouge, roulotte, souvenir, tour, tour de force, tournée, troupe*
>
>   *choucroute* (chucrut), *glamour* (glamur), *coulomb* (culombio), *goulash* (gulasch), *joule* (julio), *sioux* (siux), *soufflé* (suflé)
> - *bourbon, boy scout, chill out<sup>1</sup>, country<sup>1</sup>, house<sup>1</sup>, output, underground*.

La búsqueda para palabras que contienen "oú" solo arroja dos resultados:

> - finoúgrio (también fino-ugrio)
> - noúmeno

Como se puede ver, son todo extranjerismos (en cursiva - sin cursiva la adaptación española) o compuestos (como estadounidense, finoúngrio), por lo que además de los casos contemplados en la pregunta (**bou** y **noúmeno**), únicamente **proustiano** y **soul** (como señala acertadamente walen) cumplen los requisitos pedidos.

---

<sup>1. Estilos de música.</sup>

Comment: @walen: tienes razón con *soul*, pero lo mismo (no aparece en cursiva y no es un compuesto) se aplica a *proustiano*, *bou* y *noúmeno*. Modifico la respuesta en ese sentiudo. En cuanto al tema de la pronunciación de los extranjerismos, estamos con el problema del conocimiento de idiomas extranjeros